# Best way to pull data from MS-SQL-Server 2005 to MS-Project-CLIENT 2010?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, vba, ms-project

suppose I have a custom CRM software, writing data to MS-SQL-SERVER 2005, and I am trying to pull data from MS-SQL-SERVER to MS-Project-client 2010. I did some reading and have this questions:

1. what is the "best" way to pull data from sql-server to Ms-Project-CLIENT 2010? Can I do that "directly" without Ms-Project-SERVER?
2. how about push it back to SQL-server from ms-project-client 2010? I read somewhere using the xml structure in ms-project and it is not recommended...
3. Do I have to use VBA (in Ms Project client 2010) or VB 2010? (I have only those options: VB/VBA)

Sorry if it looks like amateurs, but I really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your application write to it's own database and it doesn't write to MS Project Server database(s).

If the assumption is correct than you definitely shouldn't care about MS Project Server. You practically have two options how to write to the database and your choice depends on things like: do you want to distribute login and password for the database to all users.

You can either write "directly" to the database using OLE DB or ADO either from .NET Add-On for MS Project or from VBA macro. Or you can create intermediate server and send your data to the server and that server will interact with the database.

But if your application writes to MS Project Server database and the server's version is 2007+ - I would highly recommend to do that either through Project Server Interface (PSI) or through MS Project Automation. When MS Project writes to database it does lot of magic and it would be better to let it does it's job or you have a great chance to corrupt the database in some way and recovery will be painful and/or expensive.

Comment: yes, the application writes to its own database (the SQL Server) and has nothing to do with MS Project Server (We don't have it.) The goal is now, first, to read the data from the SQL Server and display it in the MS Project CLIENT.
Thanks for the clue about "distributed DB login-password" :) 

Could you more specific about the intermediate server? I suppose it should be an IIS instance? I've read about that "write back from MS Project to DB", it is really dangerous..

Comment: It does not matter how the server will be implemented, the only requirement is it should be callable from client systems. E.g. it can be some web server with RESTful interface or some messaging queue or web service or even a service bound to a TCP socket.